# Accessing Teamcity build number in Gradle build script

Tags: properties, build, teamcity, gradle

How can I access the build number and VCS checkout number in a Gradle script executed by Teamcity?

In Ant I can use `${build.number}` and `${build.vcs.number.1}` respectively.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are simply JVM system properties that TeamCity sets for the Ant/Gradle JVM. You can access them with the usual Java means, for example `System.getProperty("build.number")`.

Comment: Note that this answer is now a little dated. Assuming the use of the "Gradle" runner in TeamCity (which implicitly applies a TeamCity-defined init script), you now have to do something like this: `project.teamcity["build.number"]`. [See this question for other details.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189846/how-can-i-define-the-teamcitybuild-number-property-in-gradle-from-command-li)

Comment: Any idea how to access Android app version number in TeamCity VCS labelling?

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing Android application you can access `build.number` to update apk file name accordingly:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mydemoci"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.7"

    ext.buildNumber = System.getProperty("build.number") ?: "Regular"
    archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionName-b$buildNumber"
 }
```

To test locally just run `gradlew clean build -Dbuild.number=123`

Answer (score 1):

I tested with many cases with gradle and injecting `build.number` outside variables. In my case, I use docker as a build environment so teamcity-provided environment does not be injected successfully.

There are two possibilities to inject variables to gradle. Note that `-D` and `-P` differences in below example.

```
// 1. gradle build -Pbuild.number=555
aaa = rootProject.properties.get("build.number") 

// 2. gradle bulid -Dbuild.number=444
bbb = System.getProperty("build.number")
```

`gradle --help` says `[option] task` as a command order but `task [option]` works.

An example `build.gradle` script is as below;

```
ext {
    buildNumber = (rootProject.properties.get("build.number") as Integer) ?: 1
}

android {

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode project.buildNumber
        versionName "1.3.7." + project.buildNumber.toString()
    }
```

In my case, I want to use `build.number` as a android versionCode, so parsing to Integer is required with `:?` null treatment.

Answer (score 0):

As of TeamCity 9.1.5 this is changed.   "Properties" (both "system" and "teamcity" ) properties are set as project ext properties.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Defining+and+Using+Build+Parameters+in+Build+Configuration

Very confusing when reading the overveiw page https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Parameters#ConfiguringBuildParameters-ConfigurationParameters  the use of "system" (in "system properties") had me thinking they were set as JVM System properites so I tried the Gradle mechanism as described here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
which says to use "org.gradle.project."  .. adding that with TeamCity that says to use "system." I tried to set a gradle property "repositoryUrl" as  "system.org.gradle.project.repositoryUrl"  ... 
This didn't work.  adding "properties" to the gradle command in team city showed that there was a *gradle* property called "org.gradle.project.repositoryUrl"

By trial and error I stumbled on the obvious ... and was about to report it as a docs bug .. but then found it in the documentation

Summary: In TeamCity 9.1.5+ use

```
system.<propertyName>
```

e.g.

```
system.repositoryUrl
```

In Gradle these are accessable as rootProject (or project) "properties" (not "system properties" ... e.g.

```
println repositoryUrl 
println project.repositoryUrl
println rootProject.repositoryUrl
println project.properties["repositoryUrl"]
println rootProject.ext.repositoryUrl
println "${repositryUrl}"
assert  hasProperty("repositoryUrl")
```

and the 500 other ways of doing the same thing.